# invalidate() not drawing my custom view

Tags: android, view, line, ondraw, invalidation

SOLVED: Basically if you have a scrollview/horizontal view as a parent of your custom view, you must override onMeasure and specify the dimensions of your custom view so the parent scrollview knows how much room to allocate to it, and then it will draw.

> EDIT: I've found out that the problem is because I am trying to add a
>   line to a relative layout which is wrapped in a scrollview. When I
>   remove the scrollview the line is added correctly. I'm not sure why..
>   but I need the scrollview in my app.. any ideas why this is the case
>   would be appreciated, thanks!

I'm trying to draw a line between two views I have, however it is not working, onDraw is not being called.

> ```
> my custom view class:
> ```

```
public class DrawLine extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Idea idea;
    IdeaVector ideaStartConnector;
    IdeaVector ideaStopConnector;
    Context mContext;


    public DrawLine(Context context,Idea idea) {
        super(context);
        this.idea = idea;
        this.mContext = context;
```

> // these just define starting and stopping points between the middle
>   of two seperate custom views I have.

```
        Idea stopConnectorIdea = IdeaTreeActivity.ideas.get(IdeaTreeActivity.ideas.size()-1);

        ideaStartConnector= new IdeaVector(idea.topLeftVector.x + idea.getWidth()/2,idea.topLeftVector.y+
                idea.getHeight()/2,mContext);
        ideaStopConnector = new IdeaVector(stopConnectorIdea.topLeftVector.x +
                stopConnectorIdea.getWidth()/2,stopConnectorIdea.topLeftVector.y+stopConnectorIdea
                .getHeight()/2,mContext);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }




    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.i("drawLine", "response");
        canvas.drawLine(ideaStartConnector.x,ideaStartConnector.y,ideaStopConnector.x,ideaStopConnector.y,paint);
    }
}
```

> ```
> my main activity:
> ```

```
  public void addIdeaToLayout(){
                rl.addView(idea, params); //rl is my relative layout
                DrawLine connectingLine = new DrawLine(this,idea);
                connectingLine.setWillNotDraw(false);
                rl.addView(connectingLine);
                connectingLine.invalidate();

        }
```

> debug:
>
> Not sure if this is helpful, this is the response to my drag and drop
>   event of one of the views, I basically want a line connected between
>   the new view that has been dropped and the old view:

06-18 08:39:03.131 4568-4568/? E/ScrollView: Invalid pointerId=-1 in onTouchEvent
06-18 08:39:04.784 1298-2004/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x933 imply creation of host color buffer

```
                                             [ 06-18 08:39:04.786  4568: 4568 D/         ]
                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x915c9140, tid 4568
```

06-18 08:39:07.055 4568-4568/? I/ViewRootImpl[IdeaTreeActivity]: Reporting drop result: true
06-18 08:39:07.058 4568-4568/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
06-18 08:39:07.058 1621-1648/? W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: whats the size of `connectingLine`? what is the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`?

Comment: hello, the connecting line size is measured from the starting and ending coordinates within the drawline method. I dont know what an adb shell is

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: hello, I have added the debug at the end of my post, I;m not sure if it is what you were looking for though. Thankyou

Comment: what is the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`?

Comment: is this directly available in android studio? thanks

Comment: it is a command-line tool, more https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: Hello I've found out that the problem is because I am trying to add a line to a relative layout which is wrapped in a scrollview. When I remove the scrollview the line is added correctly. I'm not sure why.. but I need the scrollview in my app. thanks

Comment: so what was it?

Comment: Basically if you have a scrollview/horizontal view as a parent of your custom view, you must override onMeasure and specify the dimensions of your custom view so the parent scrollview knows how much room to allocate to it, and then it will draw.

Comment: so my first comment `"whats the size of connectingLine?"` was not that far from it...